# ORACLE Database Reporting Issue

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the SQL query i have written to generate a report and it is sheduled in the server so every day this query get executed. But in every month when the date is 1st automated report data is empty when we received the automated email from system.

Please help me sort out this issue.

```
set serveroutput on
clear screen
set feedback off
set verify off
spool d:\STO_AC_HCIN.txt
--spool /u14/manjula/STO_AC_HCIN.txt
set pagesize 1500
set linesize 150
column ff   NOPRINT NEW_VALUE  CURR_date
column gg   NOPRINT NEW_VALUE  CURR_time
column InvDate                heading  'Inv_Date'            FORMAT date
column Qty                    heading  'Qty'                 FORMAT 999999999
select to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY') ff, 
to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') gg
from dual;
TTITLE  LEFT COL 25 'BILL CHECK STO AC HCIN '     skip 1 -
      LEFT COL 25 'LOGIWIZ LIMITED-DLx/M WMS'   skip 2 -
    'Report Date : ' CURR_DATE  skip 1 - 
    'Time : ' CURR_TIME  skip 3 -

select to_char(trunc(p.ext_date),'DD/MM/YYYY') InvDate,
           count(distinct (substr(p.loc,1,12))) +7 Qty -- Exclude sublocations 
    from prodloc_snap p,
         sku s
    where p.prod_no=s.prod_no
    and s.comp_code='HC'
    and s.prod_fam='HCIN'
    and substr(p.loc,1,3) in ('R04','R06')  -- Include only the AC racks  
    and s.sku not like '%TEST%'
    and to_char(trunc(p.ext_date),'MONYY') in
            (select to_char(sysdate-1,'MONYY') from dual)
    --and to_char(trunc(p.ext_date),'MONYY')in (select to_char(sysdate,'MONYY') from dual)
    group by to_char(trunc(p.ext_date),'DD/MM/YYYY')

repfooter skip 3 - 
left col 25 '********* End Of Report ***********'

/

set feedback on
spool off
ttitle off
repfooter off
```

Answer (score 0):

> "every month when the date is 1st automated report data is empty"

Without knowing your business rules or data it is difficult for us to solve this problem for you. But this line does look suspicious:

```
and to_char(trunc(p.ext_date),'MONYY') in (select to_char(sysdate-1,'MONYY') from dual)
```

On the first of the month the sub-query will return the *previous* month. Maybe that's right. It depends on the purpose of `ext_date`. On the other hand your posted code has an alternative filter (without `-1`) which is commented out. On the first of the month that would return the current month. Why is it commented out? Seems like somebody wasn't quite sure what the correct filter was.

So this comes down to knowing your data and your business rules. That's not something we can resolve for you. If you don't understand the domain then you need to find somebody in your organisation who does.